# Fetch returns wrong object after core data automatic migration

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a weird problem with the automatic lightweight migration in iOS updating from an older version of the app I'm working on, to the next.

In iOS5 and 6, I don't have a problem.

In iOS4 *specifically* (I don't support older than that), after the migration, querying for one type of object returns object of an incorrect type.  As in, if I did a fetch for Client objects, I got back an array of DataRecords instead.  This doesn't happen for all objects but it's ... kind of a fatal problem.

This seems to be triggered by exceeding 50 entity types in the core data.  I took my old data model and made a new version deriving from it (and set it to the new default) and all I did was add 4 more entity definitions to it.  And in iOS4 the problem occurs.

Any ideas?  I can't find anything about such a limit in the Apple docs.

Thanks!